# What should the difference be in content between thesis written submission and oral defense presentation?

Tags: thesis, presentation, thesis-committee, defense

I was just wondering if anyone has tips for a thesis defense presentation. One thing I don't understand is how it is supposed to differ from the written submission (which panelists will have already read prior to the presentation).

If my thesis is applied (statistical), should I focus less on explaining the theory and how the method works? Is there any rule of thumb to determine what to include/exclude?

How should I start/end the presentation?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a thesis advisor? This sort of question would best be answered by your advisor because they know the actual contents of the work as well as the local customs.

Comment: Is the defense presentation a public event, or just for the committee?

Comment: I think the "local customs" issue is dominant here...

Comment: it's private. but the guidelines say to present as if for a general statistical audience.

Answer (score -1):

On one hand, it should be "easy" to present something you worked on for 6 months and you should be able to give a personal insight into the topic.

On the other hand, there is a non-zero chance that the thesis was done by someone else, so the oral defense is the last chance to assess if the thesis defendent is the same person that produced the written thesis.